# How to put a comma between two columns in a text file

Tags: linux, shell-script

This is my text file:

```
0019121002313002316003135  
0057936000814000814003023  
0081638001519001523001176  
0090531001841001842002633  
0111210001515001518000912  
0115400001807001828001593
```

I want the processed output as:

```
0019121,002313,002316,003135
0057936,000814,000814,003023
0081638,001519,001523,001176
0090531,001841,001842,002633
0111210,001515,001518,000912
0115400,001807,001828,001593
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
$ sed -E 's/(.{7})(.{6})(.{6})(.{6})/\1,\2,\3,\4/' file
0019121,002313,002316,003135
0057936,000814,000814,003023
0081638,001519,001523,001176
0090531,001841,001842,002633
0111210,001515,001518,000912
0115400,001807,001828,001593
```

That is, match the bits of each line that makes up the new fields and insert comma in-between them.  The matching of a field is done using `.{7}` or `.{6}` depending on the wanted field length.

Comment: FWIW the last capturing group is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk (`gawk`) you can set explicit field widths:

```
$ gawk '{$1=$1} 1' FIELDWIDTHS='7 6 6 6' OFS=, file
0019121,002313,002316,003135
0057936,000814,000814,003023
0081638,001519,001523,001176
0090531,001841,001842,002633
0111210,001515,001518,000912
0115400,001807,001828,001593
```

See [Processing Fixed-Width Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Fixed-width-data)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is not a mistake that the first comma is after 7 characters, and the next ones are at multiples of 6, I propose

```
sed 's/\(.......\)\(......\)\(......\)/\1,\2,\3,/'
```

Comment: Thanks 4 your answer.. I got my result

Comment: @Aditya, if any answer solved the problem, please click the tick on the left to accept it, and optionally upvote it by clicking the up arrow.